# Reading lua table with word index gives random order

Tags: lua, indexing, lua-table

Following is a lua code to read a table with word indexes.
reading this into another table and printing it in output gives random order everytime it is run.

```
earthquakes = {
        date8 = "1992/01/17",
        date7 = "1971/02/09",
        date6 = "2010/04/04",
        date5 = "1987/10/19"
}
sf = string.format
earthquake_num ={}

for k, v in pairs(earthquakes) do
        table.insert(earthquake_num, {key=k,value=v})
end

for i, v in pairs (earthquake_num) do
print(sf(" row %d key = %s", i, v.value))
end
```

---

OUTPUT :
everytime in different order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Egor says the pairs iterator returns table values in an arbitrary order. To sort data and return it in a sequenced format you need to use ipairs for example

```
earthquakes = {
        date8 = "1992/01/17",
        date7 = "1971/02/09",
        date6 = "2010/04/04",
        date5 = "1987/10/19"
}
sf = string.format
earthquake_num ={}

for k, v in pairs(earthquakes) do
        table.insert(earthquake_num, {key=k,value=v})
end
table.sort(earthquake_num,function(a, b) return a.value < b.value end)
for i, v in ipairs (earthquake_num) do
print(sf(" row %d key = %s", i, v.value))
end
```

see [lua: iterate through all pairs in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584258/lua-iterate-through-all-pairs-in-table) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

This is [special feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11975401/1847592) of Lua 5.2.1 :-)
But what for this feature was introduced?
Anyway, you should not rely on ordering generated by `pairs` function.

---

**EDIT :**
This feature was introduced to fight [hash collision attacks](http://lua-users.org/wiki/HashDos) on web servers that are using Lua.
Randomized hash algorithm prevents easy generating of strings with equal hashes.
Ordering of table keys generated by `pairs` function depends on hashes of strings for string-type keys, so string keys are happened to be mixed up on every program run.

Comment: It was probably introduced to explicitly *break* any code that relied on a specific order. Thus, people who accidentally wrote such code will get incorrect behavior and fix it.

Comment: @NicolBolas, that wasn't the reason but it does have this side effect, which is good.

Answer (score 3):

From [Lua PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html) on iterators:

> The `pairs` function, which iterates over all elements in a table, is
>   similar, except that the iterator function is the next function, which
>   is a primitive function in Lua:
>
> ```
> function pairs (t)
>   return next, t, nil
> end
> ```
>
> The call next(t, k), where k is a key of the table t, returns a next key 
>   in the table, ***in an arbitrary order***. (It returns also the
>   value associated with that key, as a second return value.) The call
>   next(t, nil) returns a first pair. When there are no more pairs, next
>   returns nil.

And the enumeration for `next` states:

> ### `next (table [, index])`
>
> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified,
>   **`even for numeric indices`**. (To traverse a table in numeric order, use a numerical for or the ipairs function.)