# Why "pairs" working randomly in lua? How to fix it?

Tags: lua

Why next code:

```
local x = {X=1, Y=2, Z=3}
local y = {}

for Key, _ in pairs(x) do
    table.insert(y, Key)
end

for i, v in ipairs(y) do
    print(i, v)
end
```

Why when we run it, it always returning random result?

```
1       Z
2       Y
3       X
```

Or

```
1       Y
2       X
3       Z
```

Answer (score 3):

This is by design to reduce the risk of [hashing attacks](http://lua-users.org/wiki/HashDos). You can store the keys, sort them, and then iterate over that table with keys if you need a specific/fixed order. Also see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872567/reading-lua-table-with-word-index-gives-random-order) for a related discussion.

Comment: when using selected answer, getting this error C:\Windows\lua.exe: ml\ml.lua:135: attempt to compare two nil values
stack traceback:
        ml\ml.lua:135: in function <ml\ml.lua:135>
        [C]: in function 'table.sort'
        ml\ml.lua:135: in field 'SolveIt'
        ml\ml.lua:160: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

Comment: You are not just using the selected answer; you've integrated the selected answer in your code and made a mistake somewhere, as the selected answer works by itself. You'll have to open a new question and provide your code that doesn't work if you want to get help. I suspect your sort function evaluates the wrong attributes (`a.value < b.value`).